# Webpack load c++ modules created with node-gyp using node-loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a node js webapp that is using a c++ module called 'winprocess'. Since this does not work in the browser I am using 'express' and 'socket.io' for the communication between client and server. Here is my working example: [Github](https://github.com/JDrechsler/NodeJSExpressTimeTaskTracker)

I heard about webpack and I found a loader for it called [node-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader).

I was not able to find any working examples using this node-loader. My question is: Is it possible to load native c++ node modules using this loader without having to use an express server?

Whenever I try to import the module I get an error saying:
"winprocess.node: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dlopen' of undefined"

I tried using a different module like 'memoryjs' but I got the same error.

Has anyone used this node-loader successfully before and maybe can link me to the right direction to make this work?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: You want the native C++ code to execute in the browser…? That's not going to work whichever way you look at it.

Comment: Not in the browser. I want to use it only locally and it is working with 'express' right now as you can see in the example I posted on Github. I was just wondering if I can use this node-loader instead of using the 'express' server since webpack comes with its own dev server.